# PostgreSQL: generate_series time range from midnight to midnight

Tags: postgresql

I want to use generate_series() to return data in the format of:

```
00:00 - 01:00
01:00 - 02:00
12:00 - 13:00
```

etc

Running from midnight to midnight
Where the first column is the "start" and 2nd is the "end".

What i tried so far:

```
select 

to_char(generate_series(min(DATE 'yesterday'),
                       max(DATE 'yesterday' + '24 hours'::interval),
                       '1 hour'::interval
                      )::timestamp, 'HH24:MI') as end
```

This run from 00:00 to 00:00 but am not sure how to make it as per above how i want to break it up.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

smth like here?:

```
t=# select to_char(g,'HH24:MI'),to_char(g + '1 hour','HH24:MI') from generate_series(date_trunc('day',now()),date_trunc('day',now())+'1 day'::interval,'1 hour'::interval) g;
 to_char | to_char
---------+---------
 00:00   | 01:00
 01:00   | 02:00
 02:00   | 03:00
 03:00   | 04:00
 04:00   | 05:00
 05:00   | 06:00
 06:00   | 07:00
 07:00   | 08:00
 08:00   | 09:00
 09:00   | 10:00
 10:00   | 11:00
 11:00   | 12:00
 12:00   | 13:00
 13:00   | 14:00
 14:00   | 15:00
 15:00   | 16:00
 16:00   | 17:00
 17:00   | 18:00
 18:00   | 19:00
 19:00   | 20:00
 20:00   | 21:00
 21:00   | 22:00
 22:00   | 23:00
 23:00   | 00:00
 00:00   | 01:00
(25 rows)
```